# problem with install su jdk-7u1 in ubuntu

Tags: installation, jdk

I finished some steps of installation of jdk-7u1 in Ubuntu 1.11 until below steps.
after that step the terminal tells that there is nothing to configure. after that when I run a java file the terminal said that usr/lib/jvm/java : no such a file or directory.

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better if you try to install JAVA from Ubuntu Software Center after that you can run java programs
also follow these links
http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/
http://www.shinephp.com/install-jdk-7-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Since , You Are Telling That You Installed The Java Correctly , So You Should Try to run your Java File as "#user@root" user or simply root user.

If this doesn't work then you should try to run java from Java Directory .

> user@root:~ $ /usr/lib/jvm/